# How to Prove the Equation Analytically? [solved]

Tags: geometry, matrix-equations

I thought it is straight forward to do, but turned out to be very difficult. Normal cross product properties do not work here.

It is commonly used in 3D Problems involving multiple rotated frames, but couldn't find a source explicitly proving it. Tried random values in Matlab and the equation holds numerically.

[image: Equation]

[image: Equation2]

as response to Rahul's comment, do you mean so? :
[image: Equation3]

Comment: Your notation of cross product makes zero sense. Could you explain what it means?

Comment: edited. a vector with a cross product operator result in a skew symmetric matrix

Comment: It looks like an operator that maps vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$

Comment: First, both sides are equal iff when applied to any vector they always give the same result, so you only have to prove $(Rk)\times v=R(k\times)R^Tv$ for arbitrary $v$. Then, use the fact that the cross product is rotation invariant, i.e. $(Ru)\times(Rv) = R(u\times v)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication), we have to prove:
$$
\left[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}\right]_\times = \mathbf{R}[\mathbf{k}]_\times \mathbf{R}^\text{T}.
$$
Multiply both sides by an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$,
$$
\left[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}\right]_\times\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{R}[\mathbf{k}]_\times \mathbf{R}^\text{T}\mathbf{v}.
$$
Replace the skew-symmetric matrices with actual cross products,
$$
\left(\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}\right)\times\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{R}(\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{R}^\text{T}\mathbf{v}),
$$
and distribute (this is possible for rotation matrices)
$$
\left(\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}\right)\times\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}) \times (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{R}^\text{T}\mathbf{v})
$$
For a rotation matrix, we know $\mathbf{R}^\text{T}=\mathbf{R}^{-1}$ (equivalently $\mathbf{RR}^\text{T}=\mathbf{I}$), so
$$
\left(\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}\right)\times\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{R}\mathbf{k}) \times \mathbf{v},
$$
so we've shown the two sides are the same for all $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Neat! Thank you rajb245 and Rahul for the contributions